# DFP AD Code (Javascript) causing PHP Notice: Undefined index Errors

Tags: javascript, php, session

I've recently notice a large number of PHP "Undefined index" errors in my php logs. The errors all looked like this (but were for many different variables (this one is for gender) and different lines) and all are $_SESSION Variables:

I think worked through the related site code to work out what was causing the errors. Finally I've found if I comment out the DFP AD Slots (Javascript - shown below) the errors stop occuring. (there are more slots - I've just shown one)

Comment: js cant effect php, it can however call php files that otherwise wouldnt be ran. I dont however see any evidence of that here. How about you show line 36 of search.php

Comment: line 36 is just a PHP line using the session variable gender - $_SESSION['gender']. Many session variables are getting these errors. That said I'm very sure its related to the JS above. eg: If I comment out the JS above the session errors don't appear anymore.

Comment: Your PHP should be bullet proof, no matter what client script is calling it. See the actual PHP error in log, and correct your php script.